# Creating a count down variable with repeated days

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a data frame 'reload' and I would like to create two variable that counts down the number of days until midterm and presidential elections (the actual election day would be 0, the day before would be 1, etc.). All the days between the 2008 and 2016 elections are in the data frame, however, some days are included more than once. I cannot figure out how to create a counter that doesn't double count the days.

```
reload = pd.read_excel('master.xlsx', skiprows = 1)
```

This is a sample of the data including a repeated date entry

```
      0        1          2008-01-02   307.0   307.0  R  D   R  198  235    0  49   
      1        2          2008-01-03   306.0   306.0  R  D   R  198  235    0  49   
      2        3          2008-01-04   305.0   305.0  R  D   R  198  235    0  49   
      3        4          2008-01-05   304.0   304.0  R  D   R  198  235    0  49   
      4        5          2008-01-06   303.0   303.0  R  D   R  198  235    0  49   
      5        6          2008-01-07   302.0   302.0  R  D   R  198  235    0  49   
      ....
      6765  6766          2017-09-25     NaN     NaN  R  R   R  246  187    0  54   
      6766  6767          2017-09-25     NaN     NaN  R  R   R  246  187    0  54   
      6767  6768          2017-09-25     NaN     NaN  R  R   R  246  187    0  54
```

The two rows that have '307.0' as the first entries (the 4th and 5th columns from the left) are the counter variables I tried to create. The NaN entries occur because once I realized the counter I made wasn't going to work I stopped filling the entries.

My desired out put

```
   Date  Countdown
   0  2008-01-02          8
   1  2008-01-03          7
   2  2008-01-03          7
   3  2008-01-05          6
   4  2008-01-06          5
   5  2008-01-07          4
   6  2008-01-08          3
```

Comment: post desired output...as it is little confusing!!

Comment: What's your exact question?  Why are there `NaN` values in your counter?  What makes the counter restart?  It'd be helpful if you can explain your problem more precisely, include example data that illustrates your edge cases clearly (including repeated dates with actual numeric values), and show your target output.  FWIW, this looks like you just need to `groupby` date and then `count()`.

Comment: The NaNs are there because I didn't bother finishing making the counter the way I was (in excel) when I realized it wasn't going to work because some days have two entries. Let me try to do it with groupby and count. thanks

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear - I'll update my question. The countdown variable is supposed to count the days until to midterm and presidential elections (the actual election day would be 0, the day before would be 1, etc.) all the days between the 2008 and 2016 election are in the data frame, however some days are included more than once. I cannot figure out how to create a counter that doesn't double count the days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of a minimal example, consider:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['2008-01-02'],['2008-01-03'],['2008-01-04'],['2008-01-05'],['2008-01-05'],['2008-01-05'],['2008-01-06'],
            ['2008-01-06'],['2008-01-07'],['2008-01-08'],['2008-01-09'],['2008-01-10'],['2008-01-10'],['2008-01-11']],
            columns=['Date'])
```

Yields:

```
          Date
0   2008-01-02
1   2008-01-03
2   2008-01-04
3   2008-01-05
4   2008-01-05
5   2008-01-05
6   2008-01-06
7   2008-01-06
8   2008-01-07
9   2008-01-08
10  2008-01-09
11  2008-01-10
12  2008-01-10
13  2008-01-11
```

You can use `duplicated()` to create a Boolean mask and `cumsum()` to perform the countdown in reverse order `[::-1]`:

```
df['Countdown'] = (~df['Date'].duplicated('last'))[::-1].cumsum()-1
```

Gives:

```
          Date  Countdown
0   2008-01-02          9
1   2008-01-03          8
2   2008-01-04          7
3   2008-01-05          6
4   2008-01-05          6
5   2008-01-05          6
6   2008-01-06          5
7   2008-01-06          5
8   2008-01-07          4
9   2008-01-08          3
10  2008-01-09          2
11  2008-01-10          1
12  2008-01-10          1
13  2008-01-11          0
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want to keep the duplicate data in the data frame I just want the count to repeat itself on those days rather than increasing. I edited my question to show my desired output.

Comment: And I also need to restart the counter variable at certain dates. For instance, start a countdown from 2008-01-02 to 2008-05-02 then one from 2008-05-02 to 2009-05-02 etc all in one column.

Comment: I've edited my answer to address your first comment. In terms of restarting the counter at certain dates, that is a completely different question than what you originally posted and warrants a separate question.

Comment: Okay, I'll ask a new question.